# Strange behaviour with pip install

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to install python dependencies through `pip install`. My environment doesn't have access to python default package index ( http://pypi.python.org ) for security reasons. But I have my own pypi server. The biggest problem is that, even setting the -i flag of `pip install` with my pypi server, `pip install` still looking for packages in python default package index. When this occurs, `pip install` can't reach the python default package index, and a connection time out occurs.

Here is the command line I'm running:

```
pip install --index-url http://custom.pypi.server/simple --trusted-host custom.pypi.server -r requirements.txt -vv
```

And here is the console output:

```
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.python.org
There was an error checking the latest version of pip
ConnectTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pypi/pip/json (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x153c3ed0>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=5)'))
Getting page http://custom.pypi.server/simple/dependency/
Starting new HTTP connection (1): custom.pypi.server
"GET /simple/dependency/ HTTP/1.1" 200 277
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/setuptools_git/: [Errno 110] Connection timed out -- Some packages may not be found!
```

For the direct dependency, `pip install` acts like a charm. But, for dependencies of my dependency ( setuptools_git ), `pip install` ignores the custom pypi server.

Can someone help me?

Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
--disable-pip-version-check
```

Don't periodically check PyPI to determine whether a new version of pip is available for download. Implied with --no-index.